# Restricted least squares in R

Tags: r, restrictions

I have got to estimate a model using `R` of the form:

```
y=a1*X1+a2*X2+a3*X3
```

I need to impose the following restrictions:

```
a1, a2, a3>0
```

and

```
a1+a2+a3=1
```

I already have the inputs in a matrix called `X(ncol=3)`
Can anyone inform me about which code to use?